# How i can perform a click into specific cordinates of screen in Android View

Tags: android, click

I want to create logic that will click on screen after created, i create something like this:

```
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

MotionEvent newTouch = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            mSecondChart.getWidth() /2, mSecondChart.getHeight() /2, 0);
mSecondChart.dispatchTouchEvent(newTouch);
```

As you see i use a MpAndroidChart. I need to perform a click after creating a chart for make a line. But this didnt work.

Also i try to make click in handler. But not work too.

How i can this good?

```
private void configureSecondAndThirdChart() {
    ArrayList<CandleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new CandleEntry(2, 5.25f, 3.02f, 3.50f, 4.50f));
    CandleDataSet dataset = new CandleDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
    mSecondChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mSecondChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mSecondChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = mSecondChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
    YAxis xAxis = mSecondChart.getAxisRight();
    xAxis.setEnabled(false);
    XAxis topAxis = mSecondChart.getXAxis();
    topAxis.setEnabled(false);
    dataset.setDecreasingColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dataset.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    dataset.setIncreasingColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dataset.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    dataset.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dataset.setShadowColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dataset.setNeutralColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dataset.setNeutralColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    CandleData data = new CandleData(dataset);
    mSecondChart.setData(data);
    dataset.setColor(Color.RED);

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    MotionEvent newTouch = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            mSecondChart.getWidth() / 2, mSecondChart.getHeight() / 2, 0);
    mSecondChart.dispatchTouchEvent(newTouch);
}
```

here is my method in Fragment. I use this in OnCreatedView

Comment: As i understand you need to select some data point after creating chart?

Comment: Only a click on chart and then mSecondChart will create a line. It reason why i have everything to Transparent, becouse this will work in background and will show line for mFirstChart